# iOS data base architectural decision

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, ipad

Newbie question.
I will need to have a data base from about 200 UIImages (single of them less than 500kb size) for iPad app. Customer want to have possibility to change set of this images from time to time without releasing new version of app in appstore and app must work without connection to the web (local data base on a device). I don't see how this can be done simultaneously, I see only one common option here:

- Image data base would be stored on a server, what app customer will be able to change anytime. User will need to have web connection and every time he will start the application - existing data base will load into the app.

Main questions here:
is it possible to update data base on user's device without releasing new version of app and what data base managing system is more proper to this situation(SQLite, MySQL etc...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The photographs reside on the web server. 
A number of start-off photographs may reside within the boundle so that the app is not really empty at start. 
However, when downloading the app, the user must be online. In most cases he would still be online directly afterwards when he launches the app for the first time.

The server provides two services:

1. A quick one that just provides a version number of the
   photo-database content and/or the date of the last change to the
   photographs on the server.
2. The app frequently (not more than daily I would say) checks wether there are new images on the server or not.
3. If they are then the user is asked, whether he wants to download them.
4. If the user says YES then the app sends the version number and/or last date and/or IDs of all local photographs to the server and the
   server provides the information about which photographs have been
   added and where to download that very photograph and which have to
   be deleted.
5. Then you add or delete or update the photographs from the download source given by the server. (That may well be an URL to the
   very same server of course.)

For 200 data sets I would strongly suggest core data with SQLite - the standard stuff. 
You may then think of holding the image data in the file system or in NSData properties within the database.

Answer (score 3):

Q : is it possible to update data base on user's device without releasing new version of app?
A : Yes. It is possible.

SQLite will be perfect for you.

Comment: Am I understand right that in this case I need to implement Core data for local SQlite data base and to set regular updating of it from server?

Comment: Perfect !!! And for getting values from webserver you can do this thing in background to ur app so that user has no need to wait until it load.